# C++ Sorting .txt files using a template

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, c++11, file-io

I am trying to write a program that takes 3 input .txt files, uses a template to sort the files, and write the sorted data to 3 output files. The 3 input .txt files I am trying to sort are IntFile.txt, FloatFile.txt, and QUOTES.txt. The type of data stored in the files is integers, doubles, and strings, respectively. Right now I am trying to just get the IntFile.txt to sort and am having trouble reading the .txt file and saving it to an array to send to my template to sort. I cannot figure out a way to stop the for loop once it reads the last data from the file. The program I have written thus far is

```
`#include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <string>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include "sorting.h"
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {

    ifstream inNumbers("IntFile.txt");
    ifstream inFloaters("FloatFile.txt");
    ifstream inWords("QUOTES.txt");
    ofstream outNumbers("SortedInt.txt");
    ofstream outFloaters("SortedFloat.txt");
    ofstream outWords("SortedQuotes.txt");

    int i, length = 0;
    int data[100];

    if (!inNumbers)
    {
        cerr << "IntFile.txt file could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!inFloaters)
    {
        cerr << "FloatFile.txt file could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!inWords)
    {
        cerr << "QUOTES.txt file could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; data[i] ; ++i)
    {
        inNumbers >> data[i];
        length += 1;
    }

    sorting(data[100], length);

 }`
```

This is how the numbers appear in IntFile.txt:

```
55 67 458 23 81 33
782 375 528
405 324 950 46
14 864 551 38 167 518 630
```

Comment: Are the numbers in `IntFile.txt` on separate lines?

Comment: I edited the question to show an example input

Comment: @StephenOsborne `sorting(data[100], length);`  This does not do what you think it does.  This does not send the array to `sorting`.  It sends the (invalid) entry `data[100]` to the sorting function.

Comment: Ok thank you, so would I change it to 'sorting(data[], length);' ?

Comment: @StephenOsborne - No, `sorting(data, length)`.  Arrays decay to pointers, and the name of the array in this context serves as a pointer to the first element in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block is not right.

```
for (i = 0; data[i] ; ++i)
{
    inNumbers >> data[i];
    length += 1;
}
```

You have not initialized `data` and yet you are using the values of its members in the `for` loop.

What you need is something along the lines of the following logic:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100 && inNumbers; ++i)
{
    inNumbers >> data[i];
    if ( inNumbers )
    {
       length += 1;
    }
}
```